# kubernetes autoscaling error custome metriccs

Tags: kubernetes

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: busy-autoscaler
spec:
   behavior:
     scaleDown:
       stabilizationWindowSeconds: 10
       policies:
       - type: Percent
         value: 50
         periodSeconds: 15
   scaleTargetRef:
     apiVersion: apps/v1
     kind: Deployment
     name: busy-worker
   minReplicas: 1
   maxReplicas: 2
   metrics:
   - type: Resource
     resource:
       name: cpu
       target:
         type: Utilization
         averageUtilization: 50
```

> error: error validating "hpa.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec): unknown field "behavior" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta2.HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

```sh
$ kubectl version --short

Client Version: v1.18.0
Server Version: v1.14.9-eks-502bfb
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes unknown field "behavior"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045564/kubernetes-unknown-field-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

you can check available fields by running:

```
kubectl explain --api-version=autoscaling/v2beta2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec
```

which are:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ensure that does `kubectl api-versions` show autoscaling/v2beta2 enabled.

You might also have a problem with your server version- **v1.14.9-eks-502bfb**.

See more: [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/443).
Please let me know if it helps.